# iOS 9 App Search sendUserActivityToServer after it had been invalidated, so doing nothing

Tags: ios, swift, nsuseractivity, app-search

I want to index my notes for global search. I used [a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116608/ios-9-app-search-tutorial-introduction-to-app-search).

I added string into info.plist:

```
"myapp.com.notes.note"
```

Here is my object:

```
struct Note {

    public static let domainIdentifier = "myapp.com.notes.note"
    public var userActivityUserInfo:[String: Any] {
        return ["id": note_id]
    }
    public var userActivity: NSUserActivity {
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: Note.domainIdentifier)
        activity.title = "\(note.title)"
        activity.userInfo = userActivityUserInfo
        activity.keywords = [note.title, note.text]

        return activity
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to register it.
In my view controller I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   for note in self.notes {

      note.userActivity.becomeCurrent()
   }
}
```

But always get:

> sendUserActivityToServer, called on activity
>   EC1785C0-2904-4F0A-9885-F4DB91C4B245 after it had been invalidated, so
>   doing nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't worked with AppSearch. But my guess is it can be related to object lifecycle.

In the code you've posted there are no references to `NSUserActivity` object, so it is deallocated right after cycle body is executed.

I believe the object should persist until `resignCurrent` is called on activity.

And be vigilant, because `Note` is a struct in your code and it has a value semantic, so it is copied every time you deal with it.

Comment: Yes, i guess it is a problem, but I don't understand why strong reference is not working ? I save object to global `self.notes` and this variable should live until view controller not die ? Isn't it ?

Comment: `Note` struct is not saving `userActivity` it creates a new one on each call of a `note.userActivity`

Comment: After creation `NSUserActivity` should be stored somewhere. It can be another property or you can move activity creation from `userActivity` getter to struct initializer and store in `userActivity`.